# Keep Git Branch Name Untruncated in Shell using p10k (Oh My Zsh theme)

Tags: git, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm using a Mac (Catalina), iTerm2, Oh My Zsh (https://ohmyz.sh/), and the p10k zsh theme (https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k).

Currently my git branches are showing truncated names on iTerm2 (like `davidb/my-kewl...branch`) instead of the untruncted branch names, like:
`davidb/my-kewl-feature-branch`

**How do I turn off git branch name truncating? I want the untruncated git branch names.**

Per https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/issues/193, I'm unsure how to use the code below in my `~/.p10k.zs` file to turn off git branch name truncating. I've already tried many combinations, including Google searches, and nothing worked.

```
POWERLEVEL9K_VCS_SHORTEN_MIN_LENGTH=32
POWERLEVEL9K_VCS_SHORTEN_LENGTH=12
POWERLEVEL9K_VCS_SHORTEN_STRATEGY=truncate_middle
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

As of July 2022, the line to delete is 400

```
(( $#branch > 32 )) && branch[13,-13]="…"  # <-- this line
```

Comment: As of June 2022, the line to delete is 393

Comment: As of July 2022, the line to delete is 400

Comment: As of August 2022, the line to delete is 393. Specifically, git commit id: f9fd384d8d64022e24c83bb03ba69e415c7fa90e, which corresponds to a change on July 31, 2022.

Comment: For those looking, the file you need to look is `~/.pk10.zsh`, which is probably under `{user}/.pk10.zsh`

Comment: For those looking for a shortcut, just type `open ~/.pk10.zsh` in your terminal. This will open the default editor

Comment: like the comment above telling which line number, actually I am thinking we can use search :)

Comment: Once do it, you should run ```source ~/.zshrc```

Comment: The correct filename is `~/.p10k.zs` (not `~/.pk10.zs` as some have mentioned)

Answer (score 39):

I got the answer from the p10k zsh theme (https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k) creator Roman on Gitter:
https://gitter.im/powerlevel10k/community?utm_source=badge&utm_medium=badge&utm_campaign=pr-badge

In `~/.pk10.zsh` or `~/.p10k.zsh` delete, or comment out, line 375 as shown in this Github repo file:
https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/blob/459af1f2382ff53214bf9e4fc598b4e36fb8f8df/config/p10k-lean.zsh#L374

*Line to Comment Out or Delete in Repo Link Above*

```
(( $#where > 32 )) && where[13,-13]="…"
```

Thanks Roman!

Comment: Be great if it was an option during config.

Comment: Now the code has changed. Search for the string `<-- this line` instead, there are only 4 places. You might want to have a look at them all :)

Answer (score 4):

For those who can't find the config file, the file is located in your home directory so do a `cd ~/.p10k.zsh` or `vim ~/.p10k.zsh` to edit the file directly.
The file has all the informations about what each line does, so you just need to read the comments and you will probably find this:

```
  396     if [[ -n $VCS_STATUS_LOCAL_BRANCH ]]; then
  397       local branch=${(V)VCS_STATUS_LOCAL_BRANCH}
  398       # If local branch name is at most 32 characters long, show it in full.
  399       # Otherwise show the first 12 … the last 12.
  400       # Tip: To always show local branch name in full without truncation, delete the next line.
  401       (( $#branch > 32 )) && branch[13,-13]="…"  # <-- this line
  402       res+="${clean}${(g::)POWERLEVEL9K_VCS_BRANCH_ICON}${branch//\%/%%}"
  403     fi
```

As you see it states which line should be deleted to not have ellipsis prepended in the git branch name, in this current version line number 401.